# How to hide SIM number indicator on phone and SMS live tiles

Tags: 8.1, settings, live-tiles

I got a phone with two SIM card slots. I only use one SIM card. As shown below, there's a number 1 on the phone and SMS live tiles to indicate which SIM card it is referring to. The problem is that I see the number, and think there is a new message. Is there a way to change the display so I don't see the number on these live tiles?

[image]

Comment: I was able to change where it says "SIM 1" by changing the SIM card name in the settings, but it still shows the number next to the icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In was actually able to solve this on my own. Here are the steps to remove the SIM number indicator.

1. Tap on the phone live tile
2. Tap on the "..." in the bottom right hand corner
3. Tap on the "link tiles" option
4. Tap the "link" button at the bottom of the screen

The same process can be followed starting with the SMS/Messaging live tile, to remove the SIM number indicator from that live tile.